# Bold text using format() function

Tags: python, format

How could I turn my text bold using `format()` Python internal function and without importing any module?

Then I combine that text and introduce it in `ax.text()` function (from `matplotlib library`), so it would be very nice if I could do it throughout `format` function.

I'm surprised format function does not include a way of doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer to include an example of producing bold text in matplotlib and kept my general answer on producing bold text in linux using python:

You'll want to use **`fontweight='bold'`** as an additional argument in your function call. For the title of the plot chart below, I increased the font size and made the text bold with the following: **`plt.title('Info', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')`**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [5,2,7]
y = [2,16,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title('Info', fontsize=20, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')
plt.show()
```

You'll notice that info shows up in bold below:
[image]

**Here's an alternate way if you want to just bold only a word like in a multiword title:**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [5,2,7]
y = [2,16,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("This is my " + r"$\bf{" + 'title'  + "}$")
plt.ylabel('Y axis')
plt.xlabel('X axis')
plt.show()
```

You'll notice below that only the word `title` shows up in bold out of `This is the title`:
[image]

**_____________________________________________________________
_____________________________________________________________**
**_____________________________________________________________**

ORIGINAL ANSWER ON PRODUCING BOLD TEXT IN LINUX USING PYTHON:
For producing bold text in linux, here's with and without the format function to first illustrate the concept:

Bold a word in a sentence *without* format function (linux):

```
print("The last word in this sentence is",'\033[1m' + 'bolded' + '\033[0m')
```

[image]

**Bold a word in a sentence using the format() function (linux):**

```
print("The last word in this sentence is {}bolded{}".format('\033[1m','\033[0m'))
```

[image]

**Bold the entire sentence using the format() function (linux):**

```
print("{}This entire sentence is bolded{}".format('\033[1m','\033[0m'))
```

[image]

Comment: @Miguel Gonzalez I updated answer to add matlibplot specific bold text

Comment: Thank you very much for all the examples @EWJ00, very usefuls. I'm trying to replicate the penultimate example but no bold word is raised, not at the matplotlib images nor even at the python console. Do you think pyhon version could be generating the trouble? I'm running it at 3.7 version.

Comment: @Miguel Gonzalez, are you running this on linux?

Comment: No, on Windows. Do you know something analogous for Windows?

Comment: Oh, ok. For windows, I came across a python library called **colorama** that can help.  https://pypi.org/project/colorama/0.2.4/   There's a few working examples further down the page.

Comment: Great, thank you very much @EWJ00
Nevertheless, I'll keep trying to find something within Python not to import too many modules.

Comment: were you able to try the matplotlib example?

Comment: Yes, and it worked correctly but I'm using ax.text() function, and I don't want all the text I put inside to turn bold. That's why I was trying with format function

Comment: updated my answer with a title partially in bold

Comment: PERFECT. That syntaxis works perfectly! thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Python strings do not have attributes like fonts or colours, so there is no way for format to add them.

If you are printing to a terminal, there is a decent chance that the terminal can be controlled via codes embedded in the string, as several other answers and comments have mentioned.

However, that will not work for the matplotlib case. I am no matplotlib expert, but it looks like you can exert some control over text appearance through the optional arguments to Axes.text(), but that information will have to be conveyed separately from the text.